# Is it possible to provide estimates for status-planned features and fixes?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is it possible for the development team to add some feedback on when they might be planning to deliver features with the status-planned tag? It doesn't have to be in the form of a new feature, just an updated comment on the request. This would alert anyone following the request. Any estimates needn't be binding either.

It is easy to find the planned features, using this link...

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=status-planned&sort=votes&pagesize=50

However, the top five entries, sorted by vote are all five months old. I understand that work needs to be prioritised, but surely the user's votes must count for something.

Comment: They'll take about six to eight weeks probably...

Comment: Thanks, but I meant a comment on the actual features requested rather than on this question.

Comment: @DanielDyson Nevermind :P http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514

Comment: The first one should probably be already resolved - it's practically too late for it to matter for addressing now. The second one already is resolved, and I have flagged it to get a tag swap. I don't actually know about the 3 careers ones.

Comment: Apparently one of your devs doesn't like that idea and downvoted me. :)

Comment: Actually, it could be anyone, not just a dev. Meta Stack Overflow is populated by users from all over, and they can come up with some very abstract reasons to downvote stuff. Or, simply put, they may simply disagree that this is a wise idea.

Comment: In that case, a comment is better than a down vote. Or at least both. I consider it rude to down vote someone without explaining why. That is a disservice to everyone, because they might have a valid reason for downvoting that I haven't thought of. I never dream of down-voting without saying why.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not, but it's a good idea for us to periodically revisit this list.

I see a number of long term things on there that the NYC careers team will have to look at, for example.